# Quarantined Testing environment for PHP

Tags: php, git, testing

I'm in the process of integrating a Git repo into company workflow and the boss wants a way to be able to test the php code before deploying to production.  The goal is to have three environments: dev, test, and production.

So the workflow will be something like:

- Clone into the repo for local dev
- Push changes to the repo
- Pull changes from repo to the test env
- Test changes within the test env to show management what the site *will* look and behave like after the changes are pulled to the live env
- Upon approval, pull the changes from the repo to the production env.

Now, there are a couple catches here:

1. The company wants to use actual data from the live env to better judge if the program behaves correctly in the testing env.  I'm comfortable keeping the data in sync and essentially making the live db sync nightly to the testing db.
2. The program sends email to clients on a regular basis so I need a way to intercept any call to mail() and redirect that attempt either to a log file or to a different email address.
3. The program also handles billing, though I'm fairly confident that I can just switch payment processor integrations from live to a sandbox env (i.e. paypal, auth.net, etc..)

I'd appreciate any thoughts and ideas on how to do the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On our staging server, I have configured the local smtp to drop all mail except certain addresses that are on a whitelist. That way, customers won't receive any mails from the staging environment.

With other external services, I run them in a testing mode, if they support that or otherwise use stubs. The latter means that we don't get to test the last integration point, but that's acceptably close.

Comment: Very cool, do you have a resource you can point me to so I can learn how to configure the smtp to suit my needs?

Comment: It's pretty simple with postfix. Here's a post with instructions: http://thedrupalblog.com/configure-your-development-server-deliver-all-mail-locally

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar approaches written into apps before and have seen the following implemented:

- A standard "mail" class used to build/send all outbound emails. That way you can easily modify the behaviour in dev/staging environments. One nice way of doing it is to send all of the email from that system to either a shared mailbox or the email address of the logged in user (performing the testing) and to include a header in the mail saying that it's from the test platform and who it would have been sent to really if it was on production.
- In other setups I've seen the MTA configured to black-hole mail
- clearly defined ways of letting the app detect which environment it's running in so it can figure out how to behave. Environment variables set in the Apache config (I'm guessing you're using Apache) to detect the platform and then config functionality that allows you to inherit from a set of common options and overload with specific ones where necessary. Zend Framework's `Zend_Config` handles this really well.
- To allow for easy testing of your code or replacement of components good OO design and [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) will really help with how well you can test things
- Consider using some kind of Continuous Integration tool like Hudson or PHP Under Control
- Consider looking at Capistrano or Phing to allow easy deployment to different platforms

Comment: I like the dependency injection suggestion. That is a very useful concept.

Answer (score 1):

1. How accurate does the data need to be? Does it need to *be* the production data, or just *like* it? You might be able to get away with an import that you run manually whenever you have a schema change or something.
2. Another alternative here would be to run an update on the DB table containing your contacts which adds ".invalid" or something to the end of live e-mail addresses which wouldn't require any other configuration.
3. The sandbox environment for your payment authorizations will necessarily be a function of the gateway you're using.

I like James C's mention of dependency injection. Injected dependencies will blur the lines between your production and testing environment without requiring extensive configuration. This will definitely make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. This will be tedious if you have a large dataset. If you are using MySQL, you can capture the bin log and rerun them on test to keep the data in sync.
2. This can be achieved using an environment variable or config, which uses the debug mail id if the environment being used is a test env.
3. same configuration as above.

please be aware that when using git to push to a remote repo, the repo needs to be bare otherwise you will have to hack it.

Comment: Capturing the binlog will only work well if the staging database isn't being written to (which I'm guessing it might do as part of testing). If it is then you'll likely run into all sorts of nasty problems replaying bin log like primary key collisions, etc

Comment: We're using unfuddle as our repo host.  AFAIK I can clone into the repo, make changes, add and commit the changes, push the changes back to the repo and the changes will be appropriately represented on the remote repo.  I don't intent to attempt to push changes from the unfuddle repo to the testing/live env's

Comment: @JamesC, tru, i didnt consider that possibility.  @ivannovak, any hosted git repo would be ok, as you have mentioned. I was pointing out the case if you need to push to your own git repo.